# SQL: ERROR inserción o actualización en la tabla «children» viola la llave foránea «children_cod_matricula_fkey»

Tags: sql, postgresql, datos

ERROR:  inserción o actualización en la tabla «children» viola la llave foránea «children_cod_matricula_fkey»
DETAIL:  La llave (cod_matricula)=(1) no está presente en la tabla «grado».
SQL state: 23503

```sql
CREATE TABLE DOCENTES(
    DI_DOCENTE INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    NOMBRE TEXT,
    APELLIDO TEXT,
    TELEFONO INTEGER,
    EMAIL TEXT,
    TITULOS TEXT)

CREATE TABLE NOTA(
    COD_NOTA INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    DESCRIPCION TEXT,
    FECHA_NOTA DATE,
    FOREIGN KEY (COD_NOTA) REFERENCES CHILDREN(COD_MATRICULA),
    FOREIGN KEY(COD_NOTA) REFERENCES DOCENTES(DI_DOCENTE))
    CREATE TABLE GRADO(
    COD_GRADO INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    TIPO_GRADO TEXT,
    FOREIGN KEY (COD_GRADO)REFERENCES DOCENTES(DI_DOCENTE))

CREATE TABLE CHILDREN(
    COD_MATRICULA INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    NOMBRE TEXT,
    APELLIDO TEXT ,
    NUM_REGISTROCIVIL TEXT,
    RH TEXT,
    SEXO TEXT,
    F_NACIMIENTO TEXT,
    F_INGRESO DATE,
    ALERGIAS TEXT,
    FOREIGN KEY(COD_MATRICULA)REFERENCES NOTA(COD_NOTA),
    FOREIGN KEY(COD_MATRICULA) REFERENCES GRADO(COD_GRADO)) 

CREATE TABLE ACUDIENTE(
    DI_ACUDIENTE INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    NOMBRE TEXT,
    APELLIDO TEXT,
    DIRECCION TEXT,
    TEL TEXT,
    PARENTEZCO TEXT,
    EMAIL TEXT,
    FOREIGN KEY(DI_ACUDIENTE)REFERENCES CHILDREN(COD_MATRICULA))
CREATE TABLE PAGO_MAT(
    COD_PAGO INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    VALOR TEXT,
    FECHA_PAGO TEXT,
    CONCEPTO TEXT,
    FOREIGN KEY (COD_PAGO)REFERENCES ACUDIENTE(DI_ACUDIENTE),
    FOREIGN KEY(COD_PAGO) REFERENCES DOCENTES(DI_DOCENTE))

CREATE TABLE VENTA_PRODUCTO(
    COD_VENTA INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    FECHAVENTA TEXT,
    VALORTOTAL TEXT,
    FOREIGN KEY(COD_VENTA)REFERENCES DOCENTES(DI_DOCENTE),
    FOREIGN KEY(COD_VENTA)REFERENCES PAGO_MAT(COD_PAGO),
    FOREIGN KEY(COD_VENTA)REFERENCES PRODUCTO(COD_PRODUCTO))
    CREATE TABLE PRODUCTO(
    COD_PRODUCTO INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    NOMBRE TEXT,
    FOREIGN KEY(COD_PRODUCTO)REFERENCES INGREDIENTES(COD_INGREDIENTE))

CREATE TABLE INGREDIENTES(
    COD_INGREDIENTE INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    INGREDIENTE1 TEXT,
    INGREDIENTE22 TEXT)
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenidos a stackoverflow. El error es porque intenta a insertar/actualizar `children.cod_matricula` con un valor 1. Pero la regla de foreign key de tabla `children` declara que cualquier valor de `cod_matricula` debe ser presente en `nota.cod_nota` y `grado.cod_grado`. Basado en el detail de error, el valor (1) no está presente en grado.cod_grado.

Comment: pero el error me salio a la hora de querer ingresar datos a tabla children, entonces no se como ingresar un dato sin que me salga ese error

Comment: tienes que tener el valor 1 ```COD_MATRICULA``` en la tabla  ```GRADO``` específicamente en el campo ```COD_GRADO``` y por tu estructura también tienes que tener ese id en la tabla ```NOTA``` en el campo ```COD_NOTA```

Comment: ¿Has graficado este modelo E/R? Las llaves foráneas están mal establecidas. Por ejemplo, tienes llaves foráneas en la tabla `children`, que exigen que el `cod_matricula` exista primero en las tablas `nota` (campo `cod_nota`) y `matricula` (campo `cod_matricula`). Luego en la tabla `nota`, tienes una llave foránea que hace que para para insertar un nuevo `cod_nota`, debe existir este valor en el campo `cod_matricula` de la tabla  `children`. Esto hace imposible ingresar un `children` (ya que no puede existir la nota), que a su vez no se puede ingresar mientras no exista un `children`.

Comment: El modelo, como está definido, es inutilizable.

Comment: entonces que cambios debo hacer para poder utilizar esta base de datos , borrar forenea o que tipo de cambios debe hacer, porfavor y gracias por su ayuda